# Why AddressSanitizer can't find the exact stack when detect the wild pointer?

Tags: android, llvm-clang, address-sanitizer

I use AddressSanitizer on Android and when it detect a wild pointer bug, the stack it report is only one or two with no code call logic so I can't find what causes this wild pointer. For example, as follows, "freed by thread T123 here" has only one meaningless stack.

```
05-05 16:39:01.958   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.958   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.958   658  1596 I         : ==658==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0xb008fbf0 at pc 0xeb6b2fcc bp 0xb33f9738 sp 0xb33f9308
05-05 16:39:01.958   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.958   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.958   658  1596 I         : READ of size 65496 at 0xb008fbf0 thread T16
05-05 16:39:01.987   658  1596 I         :     #0 0xeb6b2fcb  (/system/lib/libclang_rt.asan-arm-android.so+0xaefcb)
05-05 16:39:01.987   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.987   658  1596 I         :     #1 0xc7e8209f  (/vendor/lib/hw/camera.qcom.so+0x3ef09f)
05-05 16:39:01.987   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         :     #2 0xc7e716c1  (/vendor/lib/hw/camera.qcom.so+0x3de6c1)
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         :     #3 0xc7e6e773  (/vendor/lib/hw/camera.qcom.so+0x3db773)
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         :     #4 0xc7e6dceb  (/vendor/lib/hw/camera.qcom.so+0x3daceb)
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         :     #5 0xc7e6c7c1  (/vendor/lib/hw/camera.qcom.so+0x3d97c1)
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         :     #6 0xc81cb8c5  (/vendor/lib/hw/camera.qcom.so+0x7388c5)
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         :     #7 0xc8246a2f  (/vendor/lib/hw/camera.qcom.so+0x7b3a2f)
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         :     #8 0xc8246377  (/vendor/lib/hw/camera.qcom.so+0x7b3377)
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         :     #9 0xc804b19f  (/vendor/lib/hw/camera.qcom.so+0x5b819f)
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         :     #10 0xc80497e3  (/vendor/lib/hw/camera.qcom.so+0x5b67e3)
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         :     #11 0xc80495f1  (/vendor/lib/hw/camera.qcom.so+0x5b65f1)
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         :     #12 0xec12fe05  (/system/lib/libc.so+0x63e05)
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         :     #13 0xec0ea0a5  (/system/lib/libc.so+0x1e0a5)
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I chatty  : uid=1047(cameraserver) provider@2.4-se identical 1 line
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 0xb008fbf0 is located 99312 bytes inside of 378963-byte region [0xb0077800,0xb00d4053)
05-05 16:39:01.988   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         : freed by thread T123 here:
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         :     #0 0xeb6b3e03  (/system/lib/libclang_rt.asan-arm-android.so+0xafe03)
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         :     #1 0xc71addab  (/vendor/lib/libmegface.so+0xd1dab)
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I chatty  : uid=1047(cameraserver) provider@2.4-se identical 1 line
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         : previously allocated by thread T123 here:
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         :     #0 0xeb6b414b  (/system/lib/libclang_rt.asan-arm-android.so+0xb014b)
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         :     #1 0xc74b026b  (/vendor/lib/libmegface.so+0x3d426b)
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I chatty  : uid=1047(cameraserver) provider@2.4-se identical 1 line
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         : Thread T16 created by T0 here:
05-05 16:39:01.989   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         :     #0 0xeb69ba7f  (/system/lib/libclang_rt.asan-arm-android.so+0x97a7f)
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         :     #1 0xc7f7e8d5  (/vendor/lib/hw/camera.qcom.so+0x4eb8d5)
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I chatty  : uid=1047(cameraserver) provider@2.4-se identical 1 line
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         : Thread T123 created by T122 here:
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         :     #0 0xeb69ba7f  (/system/lib/libclang_rt.asan-arm-android.so+0x97a7f)
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         :     #1 0xc71c803d  (/vendor/lib/libmegface.so+0xec03d)
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I chatty  : uid=1047(cameraserver) provider@2.4-se identical 1 line
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         : Thread T122 created by T43 (HwBinder:658_3) here:
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         :     #0 0xeb69ba7f  (/system/lib/libclang_rt.asan-arm-android.so+0x97a7f)
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         :     #1 0xc7e49bdd  (/vendor/lib/hw/camera.qcom.so+0x3b6bdd)
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.990   658  1596 I chatty  : uid=1047(cameraserver) provider@2.4-se identical 1 line
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         : Thread T43 (HwBinder:658_3) created by T41 (HwBinder:658_1) here:
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         :     #0 0xeb69ba7f  (/system/lib/libclang_rt.asan-arm-android.so+0x97a7f)
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         :     #1 0xec00fc0b  (/system/lib/vndk-sp-28/libutils.so+0xbc0b)
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I chatty  : uid=1047(cameraserver) provider@2.4-se identical 1 line
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         : Thread T41 (HwBinder:658_1) created by T0 here:
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         :     #0 0xeb69ba7f  (/system/lib/libclang_rt.asan-arm-android.so+0x97a7f)
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         :     #1 0xec00fc0b  (/system/lib/vndk-sp-28/libutils.so+0xbc0b)
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I chatty  : uid=1047(cameraserver) provider@2.4-se identical 1 line
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         : SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free (/system/lib/libclang_rt.asan-arm-android.so+0xaefcb) 
05-05 16:39:01.991   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         : Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   0xe15d1f20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   0xe15d1f30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   0xe15d1f40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   0xe15d1f50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   0xe15d1f60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         : =>0xe15d1f70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00[00]00
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   0xe15d1f80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   0xe15d1f90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   0xe15d1fa0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   0xe15d1fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   0xe15d1fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         : Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Addressable:           00
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Heap left redzone:       fa
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Freed heap region:       fd
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Stack left redzone:      f1
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Stack mid redzone:       f2
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Stack right redzone:     f3
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Stack after return:      f5
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Stack use after scope:   f8
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Global redzone:          f9
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Global init order:       f6
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Poisoned by user:        f7
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Container overflow:      fc
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Array cookie:            ac
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Intra object redzone:    bb
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   ASan internal:           fe
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Left alloca redzone:     ca
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         :   Right alloca redzone:    cb
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         : 
05-05 16:39:01.992   658  1596 I         : ==658==ABORTING
```

How can I get more information to find the exact causes of the wild pointer?

Answer (score 0):

By default Asan uses frame pointers to unwind stack which is fast but imprecise unless your code and all libs are build with `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`. You can ask it to use normal unwinder by exporting `ASAN_OPTIONS=malloc_context_size=20`.